# Xpath sequential set query

Tags: xpath

I need to locate the first element satisfying the conditions, however I must use existing part of Xpath query due to the implementation.

Reason:
I have an embedded struct in Golang to be unmarshalled later.

```
type offersDto struct {
    PinnedOffer *offerDto `xpath:"(.//div[@id='aod-pinned-offer'])[1]" xpath_required:"false"`
}

type offerDto struct {
    PriceBlock *struct {
        Price string `xpath:".//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-offscreen ')]/text()"`
    } `xpath:".//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-price ')]"`
}
```

This does not work in case the query "xpath:".//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-price ')]" has multiple matches. I do not need an array there and am wondering whether I could locate the first of multiple (or single) matches and use that.

The HTML I'm having trouble is like that:

```
<div id="aod-pinned-offer" class="a-section a-spacing-none aod-pinned-offer-block">
    <table><tbody><tr><td>
        <span>
            <div class="some-class">
               <span class="some-class">-35%</span>
               <span class="a-price some-class">
                   <span class="a-offscreen">
                       AED354.00
                   </span>
                   <span>
                       <span>AED</span><span>354<span>.</span></span><span>00</span>
                   </span>
               </span>
            </div>
            <div class="some-class">
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <span>
                            List Price:
                            <span class="a-price some-class">
                                <span class="a-offscreen">
                                    AED541.00
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    AED541.00
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I failed to find a way to query the 1st span with class `a-offscreen`, maintaining the first part of the query: `(.//div[@id='aod-pinned-offer'])[1]`.
I tried `(.//div[@id='aod-pinned-offer'])[1](.//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-price ')]//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a-offscreen ')]/text())[0]` and variations in brackets placement, however it seems two sequential set queries (like: `(some xpath)[1]`) are not supported. Any way to achieve them?

Edit: I later noticed that encoding/json unmarshaller implementation by default takes the first element if multiple are present. So my question from Go perspective was foolish. However, from Xpath perspective the right answer was provided by [@LMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834978/lmc) in the comments. The solution would be to use `[position()=1]` syntax instead of `()[1]`

Comment: Go (it's called [Go, not Golang](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang)–much in the same venue you do not say Pythonlang and Javalang)) does not have direct support for processing XPath queries, and neither does its standard library (last time I checked, at least), so, to me, this question either should not be tagged `go`, and it's about XPath in general, or you should at least specify what package implementing XPath support you're using.

Comment: `.//div[@id='aod-pinned-offer' and position()=1]` could also work. Besides, if the doc is not broken that id should be unique anyway so no need for ()[1]

Comment: Thanks! That worked, please post is as an answer. The doc is not guaranteed to be correct, so could not rely on id being unique